# How to match multiple patterns with Dir.glob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I am trying to collect the paths to all the files contained in two different directories using `Dir.glob`.

The following code works but is not very concise. Isn't there a way two match **two** patterns at once with `Dir.glob`?

```
common_file_paths = Dir.glob("app/assets/mystuff/*").reject do |path|
  File.directory?(path)
end

more_file_paths = Dir.glob("app/assets/mystuff/more/*").reject do |path|
  File.directory?(path)
end

file_paths = common_file_paths + more_file_paths
```

Comment: You want all files under app/assets/mystuff/*  and its sub-directories ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Dir.glob` also accepts an array of patterns.

```
Dir.glob(["app/assets/mystuff/*", "app/assets/mystuff/more/*"])
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do it for you .. tested it in my local machine and it works as expected.

lets say , you have the following directory and subdirectory :

```
z$ find deletpractic/
deletpractic/
deletpractic/sub_dir
deletpractic/sub_dir/file1_in_subdir.txt
deletpractic/sub_dir/file2_in_subdir.txt
deletpractic/text1
deletpractic/text2
deletpractic/text3
deletpractic/text4
deletpractic/text5
deletpractic/text6
deletpractic/text7
```

it pretty much  boils down to this  `Dir.glob("/mydir/**/*")`

```
[za]$ /usr/bin/ruby -rpp -e 'common_file_paths =    Dir.glob("/dev/deletpractic/**/*").reject do |path|   File.directory?(path) end ; pp common_file_paths'
```

Output :

```
["/dev/deletpractic/sub_dir/file1_in_subdir.txt",
 "/dev/deletpractic/sub_dir/file2_in_subdir.txt",
 "/dev/deletpractic/text1",
 "/dev/deletpractic/text2",
 "/dev/deletpractic/text3",
 "/dev/deletpractic/text4",
 "/dev/deletpractic/text5",
 "/dev/deletpractic/text6",
 "/dev/deletpractic/text7"]
```